# Bootstrap 4 : how to show single collapsible element beneath several different data toggle elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Use case : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example

I have a scenario where I have multiple data toggle components which toggles the same element.
Provided the use case is to place the collapsible element to just underneath every data toggle element whenever use click on any link.

a fiddle for original vs desired behavior could be found here (https://jsfiddle.net/34uv2ezf/)

```
<h2> Needs to be tweaked !!</h2>
  <div class="row" id="NeedsToBeTweaked">
   <div class="col-md-12">
   <div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
  </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: it's hard to understand what you need? Each card component to have link below - or multiple links to toggle only one card component??

Comment: Hi Kresimir, Its multiple links to toggle only one card component.  when user clicks on any link of "Needs to be tweaked!" section, the collapsible element should come just under the clicked card element, the way it happens in "original behavior" section.

Answer (score 0):

you must change data-target in all collapses and chang id in answer
don't forget to read comments in code

```html
<div class="container-fluid">

<h2> Needs to be tweaked !!</h2>

  <div class="row" id="NeedsToBeTweaked">
   <div class="col-md-12">
   
   
   <div id="accordion">
   <!-- One -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"> <!-- change data-target here-->
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"><!-- change id here-->
      <div class="card-body">
       This First One
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Tow -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTow" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTow"><!-- change data-target here-->
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseTow" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"> <!-- change id here-->
      <div class="card-body">
        This Second One
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Three -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree"> <!-- change data-target here-->
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
  </div>
     <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"><!-- change id here-->
      <div class="card-body">
        This Thered one
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
   </div>
  </div>
```